# Team Foundation Server 2012 install error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Trying to install any type of TFS 2012 instance returns this error:

**TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Team Foundation databases: TF400771: A step performer with name 'Administration' has already been registered.. For more information, see the configuration log.**

Looked through the log and cant really understand what is actually going wrong. There was a problem with the config database from an upgrade done last year, so I decided to do a clean install and attach the existing collection to sort it out, however, cant seem to install TFS in the first place now.

Tried on a different server of the same setup and worked ok.

Comment: Did you detach the collection before attempting the reinstall?

Comment: You are not going to solve the old problem thos way. TFS is stateful and rerunning the upgrade will not fix. You need to raise a support request with MS.

Comment: Yeah frankly its a bit of a mess, there no obvious reason why its failing to install. We detached the collections before doing all this and have migrated the databases to a new instance on a new server which all works now. We have raised the issue with Microsoft to provide a response. Not holding out much hope based on past experience, we might just rebuild the box.

Comment: @MarkEvans, 1). Check the event logs in the Event Viewer to see whether there is any useful information. 2). Also have a check on logs in the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\Logs folder. 3). Go to the %temp% folder, check out logs files named "dd_tfs_server".